# Jquery dateRangePicker - always horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I have problem with dateRangePicker. On similar pages widget is randomly in horizontal or vertical position.
I want to only horizontal. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Set **"opens": "left"** or **"opens": "right"** in daterangepicker.

left/right = horiziontal

up/down = vertical

For example:

```
    $('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "startDate": "10/09/2015",
    "endDate": "10/15/2015",
    "opens": "left"
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```